# UITableViewCell customization, where to attach subviews?

Tags: ios

when subclassing UITableViewCell to define a complete custom cell what style to set? UITableViewCellStyleDefault? Actually I don't need neither the label or the imageView, would they be allocated the same?

So when attaching my custom views to the UITableViewCell subclass, is it better to add to self, or to self.contentView?

And is it ok to do some quartz drawing in drawRect in the UITableViewCell subclass (Like background) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when subclassing UITableViewCell to define a complete custom cell what style to set? UITableViewCellStyleDefault? Actually I don't need neither the label or the imageView, would they be allocated the same?

Since you are not using any of the pre-defined UILabel or UIImageView subviews of UITableViewCell, it doesn't really matter. I just use `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`. I do not know for sure if the UILabels or the UIImageView are allocated or not. However, since there is no way to explicitly tell the UITableViewCell *not* to create those subviews, I wouldn't worry about it. Even if they are created, you aren't using them so drawing the cell will not be any slower, and since cells are reused as you scroll through the table, allocating just a few extra objects once is not going to affect your overall table view performance.

> So when attaching my custom views to the UITableViewCell subclass, is it better to add to self, or to self.contentView?

All of the content should be put in the UITableViewCell `contentView`. This will ensure that the contents behave properly when the UITableView has an index on the right or if the UITableView (or UITableViewCell) go into editing mode.

> And is it ok to do some quartz drawing in drawRect in the UITableViewCell subclass (Like background) ?

The recommended approach is for the background to be placed in the UITableViewCell `backgroundView` property. So I would not recommend doing any drawing in the UITableViewCell subclass itself. Just use the `contentView`, `backgroundView`, and `selectedBackgroundView` properties. You can create a simple UIView subclass and just set that as the `backgroundView` of the UITableViewCell, if you like.

Comment: +1 for a good answer. FYI the default labels are only allocated when/if set.

Comment: Thanks, the reason for the backgroundView is as a good practice or because any implementation of the drawRect in UITableViewCell subclass is bad for performances?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a custom `UITableViewCell`, my experience is that it's much easier to use IB instead of code--even if you prefer using code normally. I would definitely recommend taking a look at these two links:
[Creating a custom UITableViewCell in iOS 4](http://ijoshsmith.com/2011/07/16/creating-a-custom-uitableviewcell-in-ios-4/)
[Custom UITableViewCell](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/custom-uitableviewcell/)

This sounds like exactly what you're looking for -- you don't have to use the label **or** the image in this case, and you can make outlets to any custom UIViews that you need.

Comment: Thanks, I do that programmatically. I found IB to hide too much logic, but I guess one day I'll try to use it more.

Comment: @EmanueleFumagalli IB doesn't hide logic. It hides repetitive, boilerplate UI code. If you want rapid app development, use IB.

Answer (score 0):

> what style to set? UITableViewCellStyleDefault?

it depends on your aims. The most used style is UITableViewCellStyleDefault.
See [Using Cell Objects in Predefined Styles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW11)

---

> is it better to add to self, or to self.contentView?

developer.apple.com [recommends](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW30) to add subview to self.contentView (they specially call it as *contentView*).

---

> is it ok to do some quartz drawing

It also depends on your aims. If you use only images or colors for background, then customize your cell view in IB, I don't see the reasons to use qurtz framework.